# The on/off switch on my computer won’t stay on so the computer won’t boot. What can I do about it?

Tags: switch

The on/off switch on my computer won’t stay on so the computer won’t boot. What can I do about it? The computer was working just fine when suddenly the screen went dark and the computer turned off. Now, although the light goes on when I press the computer on/off switch, it doesn’t stay on.

Answer (score 5):

That switch is probably a momentary type, meaning that it sends a signal to the motherboard to power up. It's not supposed to stay closed (on). You have other issues, probably as a result of a hardware failure.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that 'switch" is not just a switch, it is also a "circuit breaker", used to protect the computer from causing a fire caused by either an overload or a short circuit inside. If it will not reset after a cooling off period, it's probably because something inside has shorted out and it is not allowing you to turn it on until that is fixed.

Comment: In this case, I don't think so, particularly because *the light goes on when I press the computer on/off switch*